# Kendo UI dropdownlist DataSource + serverGrouping error

Tags: kendo-ui

I have created a kendo ui dropdown which uses a json variable for the data as follows:

```
_listData = "[{"optionKey":"1","optionGroup":"Payments","optionValue":"Taxable allowance","optionDescription":null},{"optionKey":"2","optionGroup":"Payments","optionValue":"Taxable earnings","optionDescription":null},{"optionKey":"5","optionGroup":"Deductions","optionValue":"Pre-tax deduction","optionDescription":null},{"optionKey":"6","optionGroup":"Deductions","optionValue":"Tax deduction","optionDescription":null}]";

dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: JSON.parse(this._listData), 
    serverGrouping: true,
    group: { 
        field: "optionGroup", value: "optionGroup" 
    }
});
```

I have the grouping working - but by default it sorts alphabetically, so I set the serverGrouping to true according to Kendo UI docs.

My dropdown is defined as follows:

```
var config = new Object();
config.dataTextField = "optionValue";
config.dataValueField = "optionKey";
config.height = 258;

var optionLabelCfg = new Object();
optionLabelCfg.optionValue = this._placeholder;
optionLabelCfg.optionKey = "0";
config.optionLabel = optionLabelCfg;        }

config.filter = 'startswith';

var _dropdownlist = jq('#' + uuid + "-dropdown").kendoDropDownList(config);
_dropdownlist.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Now when I set the dataSource on the Dropdownlist, I get the following javascript error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Comment: `serverGrouping` is for server side grouping and should be defined with `transport`, show your dropdown code

Comment: Thanks Gene R - edited to include dropdown code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put dataSource definition inside dropdownlist definition:

```
<input id="test-dropdown"/>
<script>
var uuid = "test";
var _placeholder = "testPlaceHolder";
var _listData = '[{"optionKey":"1","optionGroup":"Payments","optionValue":"Taxable allowance","optionDescription":null},{"optionKey":"2","optionGroup":"Payments","optionValue":"Taxable earnings","optionDescription":null},{"optionKey":"5","optionGroup":"Deductions","optionValue":"Pre-tax deduction","optionDescription":null},{"optionKey":"6","optionGroup":"Deductions","optionValue":"Tax deduction","optionDescription":null}]';

var data = JSON.parse(_listData);
var groups = {};
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function() {
   if(groups[this.optionGroup] === undefined) groups[this.optionGroup] = i++;
   this.optionGroup = '<span data-i="'+groups[this.optionGroup]+'"></span>' + this.optionGroup; 
});

$('#' + uuid + "-dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: 'optionValue',
    dataValueField: 'optionKey',
    groupTemplate: "#=data#",
    fixedGroupTemplate: "#=data#",
    optionLabel: {
        optionValue: _placeholder,
        optionKey: "0"
    },
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: data,
        group: {
            field: "optionGroup"
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

**Updated:** kendo grouping automatically sorts groups, and not supporting alternative sorting. But here is kinda hacky workaround.

Alternatively you can add another group field and group by it and then put into `groupTemplate` and `fixedGroupTemplate` function that return your real group field value

Comment: Not sure that will help me with my issue - I need to group but I don't what the groups to be alphabetically sorted, I want to define the order myself..  If I take the serverGrouping property off the DataSource definition it works fine - but the sorting is alphabetic - I need the data to be in the order I pass it.

Comment: Thanks Gene,  The groups are now in the original order, I am how ever getting a weird issue with the order of the items within the first group.  They are not in the original order.  The dataSource has everything in the correct order.  But the dropdownList.dataItems() has the order of: 'Taxable allowance', 'Non-taxable allowance' which is incorrect and strangely not alphabetical, just in the wrong order.

Comment: @frobear then you need add `sort: { field: "..." }` to `dataSource` and add that field that give sort in original order

Comment: ok all working now, forced the sort on the original order by adding an extra property to the data.  Thanks for all of your help.